# Responsive Square grids in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, responsive-design, responsive

[image]

I want to create responsive square grids in ionic, just like shown in the image above.

But instead, I get something like showing in the image below. I searched the web I can't find any solution that does not involve using images which I am not trying to use.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in pure CSS :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square-container {
  padding: 8px;
}

.square {
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / 5);
}

.square .content {
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    height: calc(100% - 16px);
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0095ff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">8</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">9</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">10</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">11</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```